# Checking out SVN gradle project directly into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, svn

Let's say I have a few java projects on an SVN repository. If I want to check them out in an eclipse workspace at the moment, I first need to check out the projects in the workspace, then import them as gradle projects using Eclipse Buildship.

If I try to check them out using the new project wizard, it seems to just initialize another gradle project on top of what's already there, leaving me without the files I was trying to check out in the first place. What I would like is to be able to directly check these out as gradle projects, in a one-step process as opposed to checking them out and then re-importing them into my workspace. Is this possible? If so, what plug-ins or gradle build configurations are necessary to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Right-click on your project at Project Explorer -> Configure -> Add Gradle Nature` should change your project's configuration to a Gradle project without creating any configuration file.